# How to get an array of permutations of array elements?

Tags: javascript, math

```
var a = [1,2,3]//may be a is [1,2,3,4,5,6...]
```

How to show a two-dimensional array from the variable `a`?

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [2,1,3],
  [1,3,2],
  [3,2,1]
]
```

this is my code :

```
var result = [];
for(i=0,i<Math.pow(a.length-1,2);i++){
    var tmp = [];
    tmp.push(...)

    result.push(tmp)
};

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Are you looking to get permutations?

Comment: please explain with more detail what you want to achieve

Comment: @zjm1126: your desired output does not match all permutations of [1,2,3].

Comment: I saw that code on geekviewpoint.com under Numbers. try www.geekviewpoint.com/Numbers_functions_in_java/. I see a lot of algorithms implementation there.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following, which takes an array as argument and returns a 2-d array containing perms of array.length

```
var permArr = [],
usedChars = [];

function permute(input) {
    var i, ch;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
        usedChars.push(ch);
        if (input.length == 0) {
            permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
        }
        permute(input);
        input.splice(i, 0, ch);
        usedChars.pop();
    }
    return permArr
};


console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]));​
```

Comment: what if the values are duplicate means if a = [1,2,2,3] ?